# Curved lorentzian fit for the peak

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, model-fitting, lmfit

I am fitting a lorentzian fit to my data and I see that the fit at the peak is not very smooth. This is due to the lack of points at the peak.

[image]

Would there be a way to get a nice curve at the peak? What parameters do I need to tweak in lmfit?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit.models import LorentzianModel

freq = [2250, 2350, 2450, 2500, 2550, 2600, 2650, 2700, 2750, 2800, 2850, 2950, 3050]

voltage = [0.00168011, 0.00200981, 0.0026012, 0.00316791, 0.00461706, 0.00782037, 0.00701009, 
           0.00372111, 0.00235486, 0.00165404, 0.00130805, 0.000879696, 0.000650067]

model = LorentzianModel()
params = model.guess(voltage, x=freq)

result = model.fit(voltage, params, x=freq)

result.plot_fit()

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not the fit, it's the way you're sampling it

Comment: @Code J: May I know whether you found an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the model with a more points for the x-axis using [Model.eval](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html?highlight=eval#lmfit.model.Model.eval) as described in the documentation.

Comment: I'd say one line of code on how this is done, would not hurt...to not make it a link-only answer.